# Get multiple selected rows info of an uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have so far a tableView that works with multiple selection rows. Everything is working fine except when I'm trying to get an array of the rows that I've selected.

This is my Stat.swift class:

```
class Stat: Equatable {
      var statName: String = ""
      var statCalendar: String = ""
      var statEvents : [StatEvents] = []
}

struct StatEvents {
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var name: String
    var dateRanges: [String]
    var hours: Int
}
func == (lhs: Stat, rhs: Stat) -> Bool {
     return (lhs.statEvents == rhs.statEvents)
}
```

And here is my EventsViewController.swift class:

```
var currentStat = Stat()
var selectedMarks = [StatEvents]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8.0)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].name)  \(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].dateRanges) horas=\(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].hours)"

    if currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].isSelected{
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].isSelected = !currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row].isSelected

    if (contains(selectedMarks, currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row])) {
        //To-Do: remove the object in selectedMarks
    } else {
        selectedMarks.append(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row]) //add the object to selectedMarks
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is in the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method. When I select any row, it appends the object in the "selectedMarks" array (this is working fine), but the problem is when I deselect some of those rows, it should erase back the object in the selectedMarks array. I'm trying to use the "contains" method, but I get a compilation error in that line

> could not find an overload for contains that accepts the supplied arguments

I updated my question by adding the Equatable protocol in the Stat class, but I get the same error again:

> could not find an overload for contains that accepts the supplied arguments

and also getting a new error:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: a quick side note: is it important that your `StatEvents` are stored in an Array? another interesting solution might be to instead use a Set (which, in addition to your `StatEvent` type adopting `Equatable` would also require it to adopt `Hashable`) - then in the body of `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` instead of checking whether the Array already contains the member and deciding whether to add or remove, you could use the Set instance method `exclusiveOr(_:)` or `exclusiveOrInPlace(_:)` - of course there would probably implications elsewhere throughout your code, but just a thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `contains` method to do its job in Swift 2, your `StatEvents` struct should conform to the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs9Equatable) protocol as in the example below:

```
struct StatEvents: Equatable
{
    // ...  
    // implementation of your structure....
    // ...
}    

// Needed for conforming to the Equatable protocol

func == (lhs: StatEvents, rhs: StatEvents) -> Bool
{
    // Return true if the parameters are equal to each other
}
```

Also, there is no global `contains` function in Swift 2, so you need to call the new array extension method `contains` instead, which in your case would be like this:

```
selectedMarks.contains(currentStat.statEvents[indexPath.row])
```

Also add the protocol declaration to the `StatEvents` structure, not to the `Stat` class. Your implementation of the `==` method is also incorrect. It should check for the equality between two object of the `StatEvents` type as I have shown above.

Comment: I edited my question, can you please check it out? I don't know what I'm doing wrong...